# How to add images to video at specific timestamps for a short time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to create a blank video and add images (occupying the entire screen) throughout the video for a very short amount of time (a frame or a second).

I found a command to create the blank video:

> ffmpeg -t 7200 -s 640x480 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 25 -i /dev/zero empty.mpeg

Now let's say I have an image. I want to insert the image into the video at the 8th second (or some other arbitrary second), and I want it to remain there only briefly.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color), [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref), and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filters. Include the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) with an [expression](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=640x480:d=7200 -i iamge.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih[fg][bg];[bg][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='eq(t,8)'[v]" -map "[v]" output
```